# Setting android:animateLayoutChanges programmatically

Tags: android, animation, dynamic

I am creating linearLayouts programmatically and would like them to fade in and out when the visibility is set to visible/gone.

I can set

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

in the xml-file, but since I am creating the views programmatically, I need to set it programmatically. How can I do that?

Answer (score 174):

Use this code:

```
container.setLayoutTransition(new LayoutTransition());
```

or

```
LayoutTransition lt = new LayoutTransition();
lt.disableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.DISAPPEARING);
container.setLayoutTransition(lt);
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but unfortunately disableTransitionType is only available from API level 16, however I am using API level 15.

Comment: It's optional, you can use simply `container.setLayoutTransition(new LayoutTransition())`

Comment: Okay, but if I wanted to disable the fade-out effect, is there a way for API level 15?

Comment: Why disable disappearing transition?

Comment: To do it in api level less than 16, just disable Animators for this transition types. This is mentioned in the documentation: 
http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/animation/LayoutTransition.html#setAnimator%28int,%20android.animation.Animator%29

LayoutTransition lt = cardsGroup.getLayoutTransition();
            // disabling appearing / disappearing layout transitions
            lt.setAnimator(LayoutTransition.APPEARING, null);
            lt.setAnimator(LayoutTransition.DISAPPEARING, null);
            lt.setAnimator(LayoutTransition.CHANGE_DISAPPEARING, null);

Answer (score 22):

To disable the fade-out effect try this:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.test_layout);
layout.setLayoutTransition(null);
```

Comment: This is giving me NullPointerException.

Comment: @SrujanBarai Then there is no view with the id `R.id. test_layout` in your layout.